# Local compactness of metric spaces and normality like condition

Tags: general-topology

Assume $X$ is locally compact metric space.

Given closed subset $A$ of $X$ and open set $U$ such that $A\subseteq U$. Show that there exists open set $V$ with compact closure such that $A\subseteq V\subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq U$.

My attempt: We know $X$ is a normal metric space, so we can find close set $W$ such that $A\subseteq W\subseteq \overline{W}\subseteq U$. I am not sure how to get $W$ to be precompact.

I guess one can get it if one show that for each pair $A,B$ of disjoint closed sets, there exists open set with compact closure such that the intersection of their closures is disjoint, however im not able to get it in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is fasle and there are simple counter-examples: Take $A=\mathbb N$ and $U=\mathbb R$ in the real line with the usual metric. Here, $A$ is not contained in any compact set.